# How to group each set of array with the array key in laravel/php?

Tags: php, laravel, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to split the arrays and name them or group them individually. When the form is submitted, all the inputs are in array. For example, `<input type="text" name="fname[]"` and so on. When I get the input in the controller they are group by fname 1 to 4. So, I wanted to split each of the first object in the array. Please find the code below of what I am getting now and my desire output I want:-

I have created a form where I am collecting the data and sending it to the controller.

```
// Family Members form
//this family form will add 3 more times as the total member in this fmaily are 4 who are still living
@for($i=1;$i<= $totalMembs;$i++) 
<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="{{$i}}" >
<input type="text" name="fname[]" value="" >
<input type="text" name="lname[]" value="" >
<input type="date" name="dob[]" value="" >
<input type="radio" name="gender[{{$i}}]" id="genderM" value="male" >
<input type="radio" name="gender[{{$i}}]" id="genderF" value="female">
 <select name="nationality[]" id="nationality{{$i}}">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="India">Indian</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
    <option value="AUS">AUS</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" name="birthPlace[]" value="">
 <select name="state[]" id="state{{$i}}">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="MH">Maharashtra</option>
    <option value="GJ">Gujrat</option>
    <option value="DL">Delhi</option>
    <option value="MP">Madya Pradesh</option>
 </select>
 <select name="device[]" id="device{{$i}}">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
    <option value="Landline">Landline</option> 
 </select>
 <input type="text" name="countryCallingCode[]" value="+91">
 <input type="text" name="telnumber[]" value="">
 <input type="email" name="email[]" value="">
 @endfor
```

When I do `dd($request->all();`, I get everything in the group of firstname:

```
"fname" => array:4 [▶]
"sname" => array:4 [▶]
```

The following is the output I am getting in JSON:

```
"_token": "8p8hu86Oi4FMZnak0si3wK629dDejyB07abxJIpJ",
"fname": [
"Kunal",
"Manisha",
"Vinay",
"Rishi"
],

"sname": [
"Parekh",
"Sevani",
"Parekh",
"Parekh"
],
"contactEmail": [
"kunal@gmail.com",
"manisha@icloud.com",
"vinay@gmail.com",
"rishi@icloud.com"
],
"state": [
"MH",
"MH",
"MH",
"MH"
 ],
"contactTelCode": [
"91",
"91",
"91",
"91"
],
"phone": [
"0439378608",
"0778777767",
"0790123223",
"048293023"
],
"dateofBirth": [
"1981-10-18",
"1976-11-17",
"2009-04-12",
"182004-07-03"
],
"birthPlace": [
"Mumbai",
"Mumbai",
"Mumbai",
"Rajkot"
],
"genderType": {
"1": "male",
"2": "female",
"3": "male",
"4": "male"
},


"nationality": [
"Indian",
"Indian",
"Indian",
"Indian"
],

}
```

And the output I want is:

```
"family": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "dateOfBirth":  "1981-10-18" ,
        "gender":   "male"  ,
        "name": {
            "firstName": [
                "Kunal" 
            ],
            "lastName": [
                "Parekh" 
            ]
        },
        "currentplace": {
            "nationality": "INDIAN" ,
            "birthPlace":  "Mumbai"  ,
        },
        "contact": {
            "state": "MH",
            "phones": {
                "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                "countryCallingCode": "91",
                "number": "980080076"
             }
                "emailAddress": "kunal@k.com"  
            }
            
        },
        
    },
     {
        "id": 2,
        "dateOfBirth":  "1976-11-17",
        "gender":   "female" , 
        "name": {
            "firstName": [
                "Manisha" 
            ],
            "lastName": [
                "Parekh" 
            ]
        },
        "currentplace": {
            "nationality": "INDIAN"  ,
            "birthPlace" : "Mumbai"  ,
        },
        "contact": {
            "state": "MH",
            "phones": {
                "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                "countryCallingCode": "91",
                "number": "980080075"
                "emailAddress": "manisha@m.com"  
            }
            
        },
        
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "dateOfBirth": "2009-04-12" , 
         
        "gender":  "male"  ,
        "name": {
            "firstName": [
                "Vinay" 
            ],
            "lastName": [
                "Parekh" 
            ]
        },
        "currentplace": {
            "nationality": "INDIAN"  ,
            "birthPlace":  "Mumbai" , 
        },
        "contact": {
            "state": "MH",
            "phones": {
                "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                "countryCallingCode": "91",
                "number": "980080074"
             }
                "emailAddress":   "vinay@v.com"  
            }
            
        },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "dateOfBirth": "2004-07-03" ,  
        "gender":  "1": "male" ,
        "name": {
            "firstName": [
                "Rishi" 
            ],
            "lastName": [
                "Parekh" 
            ]
        },
        "currentplace": {
            "nationality":  "INDIAN"  ,
            "birthPlace":    "Mumbai" ,
        },
        "contact": {
            "state": "MH",
            "phones": {
                "deviceType": "MOBILE",
                "countryCallingCode": "91",
                "number": "980080073"
             }
                "emailAddress": "rishi@r.com"  
            }
            
        },
 
    ]
```

Please let me know how to group the array as shown in the output above.

Comment: can you include your form

Comment: actually the form is generated dynamically depending how many family in the house/home. Let me try

Comment: i am not getting the form unfortunately

Comment: Will be good if you share the backend code which you tried.

Comment: alright, let me try. Please give me few minutes. Thx

Comment: @user10345537 provide the blade template used to generate the form or whatever frontend you are using

Comment: Hi i have submitted the basic code for the form. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254563/discussion-between-js-tech-and-user10345537).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something that matches your expected output:

```
$arr = $request->all();

$results = [];

for ($i=0; $i < count($arr["fname"]); $i++) {

    $results["family"][] = [
        "id" => $i + 1,
        "dateOfBirth" => $arr["dateofBirth"][$i],
        "gender" => $arr["genderType"][$i + 1],
        "name" => [
            "firstName" => $arr["fname"][$i],
            "lastName" => $arr["sname"][$i]
        ],
        "currentplace" => [
            "nationality" => $arr["nationality"][$i],
            "birthPlace" => $arr["birthPlace"][$i]
        ],
        "contact" => [
            "state" => "MH",
            "phones" => [
                "deviceType" => "MOBILE",
                "countryCallingCode" => $arr["contactTelCode"][$i],
                "number" => $arr["phone"][$i],
            ],
            "emailAddress" => $arr["contactEmail"][$i]
        ]
    ];
}
 
return $results;
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error **Undefined array key "family"**. Actually the "family" I created inside the array. But when I do the `request->all()` i actually get this on my screen :- "fname" => array:4 [▶]
"sname" => array:4 [▶]

Comment: I have edit my question and you can see the output msg i get. Thx

Comment: output for `$request->all()` I get :` "fname" => array:4 [▶]
"sname" => array:4 [▶] `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254563/discussion-between-js-tech-and-user10345537).

Comment: @JSTECH why map the data in controller after submission, when you can submit the data in the correct format in the first place

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, each object should have the same key in the `fname` array

```php
@foreach(range(1, $totalMembs) as $member)
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][id]">
  <input type="date" name="fname[{{ $member }}][dateOfBirth]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][gender]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][name][firstName]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][name][lastName]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][currentplace][nationality]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][currentplace][birthPlace]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][contact][state]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][contact][phones][deviceType]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][contact][phones][countryCallingCode]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][contact][phones][number]">
  <input type="text" name="fname[{{ $member }}][contact][emailAddress]">
@endforeach
```

Comment: Well, in the example given by you above, at this stage I do not have any `$member->id`. The user when fills the form and enters 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 etc as members in their house, it come on this page/blade where the form adds up accordingly to what the user typed on the previous page

Comment: ahh ok I though `$totalMembs` was a list of objects

Comment: @user10345537 but if you don't have any member ids, why try to include a field of `id` in this form. The ID of each member should be resolved by the server after the form is submitted.

Comment: I am just updating my question on how I got this in to JSON. Please bare with me.... thanks